# Have backlinks to point of reference generated automatically

Tags: cross-referencing, links

I'm looking into replacing an existing documentation system with on based on LaTeX. In this system we have the possibility to link between sections (even if the sections are in different documents. A link from one document to another automatically set up a link going in the opposite direction. What I'd want is something like the following:

Document 1:
`Inlinks~\magiclabel{d1-l1}`

Document 2:
`Outlinks~\magicref{d1-l1}`

Document 3:
`Outlinks~\magicref{d1-l1}`

That should generate the following:
Document 1:
Inlinks [d2-ref1, d3-ref1]

Document 2:
Outlinks [d1-l1]

Document 3:
Outlinks [d1-l1]

Is such a thing even possible?

Edit:
Ideally, I would like to have the links clickable. I.e. click d1-l1 in Document 2 to go to Document 1, and then click d2-ref to go back to Document 2.

Comment: Package `hyperref` and its `\hyperlink`, `'\hypertarget`, `\href` and `\hyperref` commands should do, what you request

Comment: I tried replacing my `\magiclabel` with `\hypertarget`and my `\magicref` with `\hyperlink`. This seems to work in one direction, but the list of incoming links do not appear at the `\hypertarget`.

Comment: Well, you can place one label at a position and refer to it at multiple positions, but each position can have only one backlink -- how should the link know which source it has. A strategy is `\hypertarget{foo:dest}{\hyperlink{foobar:dest}{Link to the foobar file}}` and at the foo file position `\hypertarget{foobar:dest}{\hyperlink{foo:dest}{Go back to the foo file}}` -- this provides mutual backlinks

Answer (score 4):

> The hyperref package allows that by setting the option
>   pagebackref=true on the package options. Now you just have to use
>
> \usepackage[pagebackref=true]{hyperref}

https://www.sixhat.net/latex-tip-back-references-in-bibliography.html

Comment: [It seems](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.text.tex/c/ajlrHAkrWPI?pli=1) this has to be done on the `\usepackage[]` line, and doesn't work if you put it in `\hypersetup{pagebackref=true}`. I get the error `Package hyperref Warning: Option 'pagebackref' has already been used, setting the option has no effect on input line <#>`